# why am I unable to open a new activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making an app and I cannot figure out how to open one activity from another....
I have a button and when clicked, I want it to open another activity, but it is not working.
In my home.kt file, I have:

```
val button3 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button3)
button3.setOnClickListener {
    val Intent = Intent(this, muse_pick_duration::class.java)
    startActivity(Intent)
}
```

My current activity is muse_home and the activity I want to open with button3 is pick_duration. This is how I registered them in my manifest file:

[image]

button 3 is the button's id and I want it to open the muse_pick_duration activity.

Does anyone know what's wrong with this?

Comment: If you are getting errors, you should put them here, but I could try asking if you added the activity in your manifest file?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: I did add it to my manifest file and I have no errors....

Comment: `muse_pick_duration::class.java` remove .java.

Comment: try Intent(this@CurrentActivityName, muse_pick_duration::class.java) instead of Intent(this, muse_pick_duration::class.java)

Comment: Be aware that the second param in the Intent constructor should be registered in Manifest a must be an activity name. For example:  Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java)

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't open the new activity...  I just edited my original question with the manifest. Idk if I registered the files correctly in manifest.......

Comment: Could you also provide error which are you getting?

Comment: I don't have any errors, I just cant open the new activity when I click on button3 in the emulator

Comment: Have you confirmed that 1) your code in `onClickListener` is being called when you click the button (add your own log/print statement and check), and 2) that there are no relevant messages in the Logcat when you click on it? You need to be more specific than "I just cant open it" - does the app close when you click it? Or nothing happens at all? You should show enough of the `onCreate` code to replicate your issue - the cause could be something else entirely that we can't see (e.g. calling `setContentView` twice)

Comment: In my logcat, this is what I get:          
"2023-01-01 20:02:32.398 5679-5695/com.tammy.tammycogni W/System: A resource failed to call close. " Skipped 31 frames!" " The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" "JNI critical lock held for 19.074ms on Thread[1,tid=5755,Runnable,Thread*=0xe3286210,peer=0x7259ec28,"main"] "                           Nothing happens when I click on next, it just stays on the same activity....